# Using a .lib built with Visual Studio in Eclipse/CDT/gcc

Tags: windows, gcc, linker, eclipse-cdt

I am having some trouble compiling a programm with gcc on windows which was initially developed with Visual Studio. So far I was able to resolve almost all problems like missing header files and such, but now I am stuck at one last thing: gcc fails to link to one of the third party libs my program uses (FlyCapture2.lib). It tells me that it does not find any of the functions/methods there. I already checked if the library is actually on the library path and that sort of things, but it still does not work.

I searched a bit around and learned that it might have something to do with the format of .libs created with the Microsoft compiler. Is there any way to convert such a lib to be compatible with gcc? Anything else I might have missed?

(I already found this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471503/eclipse-cdt-problem-linking-to-windows-lib-files), but its solution won't work here)

Answer (score 0):

In this [page](http://wyw.dcweb.cn/dllfaq.htm) the author gives several ways to achieve what you want

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. reimp tells me, that it somehow can't read the lib and the other method using pexports/dlltool does indeed produce something, but it still fails to link against this new lib. As I read in other sources, it might actually be impossible to convert a VS lib to a gcc lib.